# Vigenere cipher? Am I doing this right?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I got `stop calling stop calling` but after that, I'm not sure if I did the standard Vigenere cipher correctly...

```
Decrypt the message `dtrn utzaknr dbbv utzaknr T lbt’b zoam po gabbd hvlwoec`,
which was encrypted using a Vigenere cipher with key word lady.
Which type of Vigenere cipher was used?
```

[image: my answer]

Comment: You are ignoring the apostrophe in the ciphertext.  Maybe it was encrypted and is throwing you off?

Comment: The apostrophe wasn't encrypted. The problem is with the second L in the second "CALLING" - he decrypted it to a 15 when it should have been an 11.

Comment: Also, beginning of third line should be the letter D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second L in your second "STOP CALLING" should be an 11, not a 15. That's throwing off the 'E' that you have, since it should be a different letter. Most of the rest is correct, but every 4th letter is off.